# InternalOAuthError: Failed to obtain access token? - NodeJS Passport

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, passport.js

I've been trying all day but I couldn't solve it.
The problem is as follows;
I made an oauth2 system for my own website. But it gives me the error in the title.

I guess it doesn't detect the callback coming from the server side?

```
res.redirect('http://localhost:2000/callback?code=' + response.data.accessToken);
//Example => http://localhost:2000/callback?code=97a1438b602c76a680297426306785ec9ef49f43
```

The piece of code where I got the error;

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let token = 'http://localhost:3000/oauth/token';
let authorization = 'http://localhost:3000/login';
let temproraydata = {};

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var passport = require('passport');
var OAuth2Strategy = require('passport-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;

passport.use(new OAuth2Strategy({
    authorizationURL: authorization,
    tokenURL: token,
    clientID: 'application',
    clientSecret: 'secret',
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:2000/callback",
    passReqToCallback: true
},
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        console.log(accessToken);
        console.log(refreshToken);
        temproraydata = profile;
        return done(null, profile);
    }
));

app.get('/provider', passport.authenticate('oauth2', { session: false }));
app.get('/callback',
    passport.authenticate('oauth2', {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/login'
    }));


app.listen(2000, function () {
    console.log("Listening on port 2000");
});
```

this is error;
[images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmxcg.png)

I've been working on it all day. I have done oauth server side but I am having problems on user side. I can't figure it out, I'm waiting for your help.

Comment: But hard to understand at which step it goes wrong. Do you get redirected to your external oauth2 server and does that oauth2 server send you back with a `code` in the URI?  The `res.redirect` with the `code` argument doesn't really make sense as the `code` is not an `accessToken` and you wouldn't need to build this URI (the oauth2 server does)

Comment: @Evert The code sent is an accessToken.
Except for the code parameter, it redirects to the previous page.

Comment: If you got an `accessToken` in the `code` parameter, then this is not OAuth2. Are you building your own OAuth2 server?